# Bean lifecycle in Spring Boot 2.1 and Java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

My project is moving from Spring Boot 2.0.4 with Java 8 to Spring Boot 2.1.0 with Java 11. When the application was built with Spring Boot 2.0.4 and Java 8 and run in Docker / Docker Compose, the `@PostConstruct`-annotated method was called, but after the move to Spring Boot 2.1.0 and Java 11 the `@PreDestroy`-annotated method is no longer called.

I have tried switching from annotations to implementing `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean` as described [here](https://better-coding.com/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-alternatives-in-java-9/), but the `DisposableBean.destroy` method is not called.

I have also tried adding a dependency to javax.annotation-api version 1.3.2, with the same result.

How to reproduce:

Create a minimal Spring application with a lifecycle bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Life implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("--- Life.shutdown");
    }
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("--- Life.startup");
    }
}
```

Start the Spring application from the target subfolder:

```
cd target
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When the application is stopped using Ctrl+C, the DisposableBean.destroy is called.

Return to the parent folder:

```
cd ..
```

Start the Spring application using Maven:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

When the application is stopped using Ctrl+C, the DisposableBean.destroy is called.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.1-jre-slim
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app.jar
```

Build, run, and stop Docker image:

```
docker build -t demo .
docker run -p 8080:8080 demo
docker ps
docker stats 3ca5b804ab13
docker stop 3ca5b804ab13
docker logs 3ca5b804ab13
```

When the application is stopped using docker stop, the DisposableBean.destroy is not called.

docker-compose.yml:

```
demo:
  image: demo
  ports:
  - '8080:8080'
```

Run Docker image using Docker Compose (simulating OpenShift):

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose down
demo_demo_1 exited with code 137
```

When the application is stopped using docker-compose down, the DisposableBean.destroy is not called.

I suspect that Docker is trying a SIGTERM before it issues a SIGKILL, because there is a 10-second delay before the container is killed.

Comment: Could it be that something is killing the JVM with `SIGKILL`?

Comment: hard to diagnose anything without seeing any kind of configuration files, docker  compose files, etc. etc. Can you reproduce the problem when just running directly on the metal and not involving docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution (in [this blog entry](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)): Use exec form instead of shell form in the Dockerfile so that the SIGTERM that Docker issues hits the java process instead of the bash process (which doesn't forward signals to any child processes).

- Shell form (executed with a /bin/sh -c shell):
     `ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app.jar`
- Exec form (executed without a shell):
     `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]`

Answer (score 1):

There are many places where the setup can go wrong.
First I suggest to identify whether java/spring part have some issues or it a docker/environment related issue. From the question it sounds like its java related, but in reality I suspect its not in java/spring.

So, `mvn spring-boot:run` works as expected, and I see that you package the spring boot application as jar (app.jar) likely with a spring boot plugin. This is also a place where things potentially can go wrong, because spring boot uses a special classloader to load things in runtime.

So in order to fully eliminate the "java/spring" part navigate to your `target` directory and run `java -jar app.jar` (make sure that java 11 is installed on your local machine of course).  If it doesn't work - investigate java /spring part, otherwise proceed with docker part.

The chances are that the application will work as expected.

Now, as for docker setup. 
After running docker compose and seeing that it fails,

You can use the following commands:

```
docker ps -a // -a flag to see container ids of containers that were stopped for whatever reason as well.
```

Now get find the Id of the java process that exited and examine its logs:

```
docker logs <ID_OF_THE_EXTED_CONTAINER_GOES_HERE>
```

Now the chances are that the application context fails to start (maybe network related issue or something, here it's really hard to tell without seeing an actual log) and hence the issue.

Another possible issue is that the application is "too heavy" (by this I mean that it exceeds some quotas imposed on docker container).

You can run `docker stats <CONTAINER_ID>` command to see its memory / cpu usage in real time or gather metrics from within the application.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions - I have edited my question to include the extra steps. So, the application works as expected when run directly in the JVM (from the command line or via Maven), but not when run in Docker. My demo application is a very lightweight Spring project with a simple "hello" method that responds to an HTTP request at localhost:8080.

The docker logs command shows the same as the console window, so I didn't find any extra information there.

Comment: The output from the docker logs command (after the container has been stopped using the docker stop command) ends with the last line displayed when the container was started:

2018-12-03 05:40:12.487  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.791 seconds (JVM running for 4.374)